# transform a list of different size arrays to one tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor

when the size of the arrays is equal, everything works great

```
def my_collate(batch):
    x = [np.array(item[0]) for item in batch] # output example: [array([[5,4],[5,8]]), array([[4,7],[3,7]])]
    x = np.stack(x)                           # output example: [[[5 4],[5 8]],[[4 7],[3 7]]]
    x = torch.Tensor(x)                       # output example: tensor([[[5.,4.],[5.,8.]],[[4.,7.],[3.,7.]]])
    return [x]
```

I need the tensor to also accept a list with different size of arrays (like [array([[5],[8]]), array([[4,7],[3,7]])]) and still keep the separation between the original arrays. Therefore, vstack don't work for me. Maybe it could help to pad the arrays to the same size.
I google a bit to find a code for that. I found some examples to find the largest array in a list and pad all arrays to that size, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: your example has a (2,1) and (2,2).  What shape and dtype do you want?  Why not stick with the list?

Comment: Thats just an example. It is a 3D segmentation task in which the number of points that belong together can vary greatly. Therefore I need a solution in which the largest array within the list is determined in each round and pad all other arrays. Using the list is not an option for the rest of the code

Comment: Usually in ML problems images are resized to a common size.  I don't know how padded arrays will work, since all those extra 0's (or nan) could mess up the interpretation.  Anyways there have been a lot of SO about padding arrays so they can be concatenated into one.  You'll have to iterate on the arrays on the list at least once (to determine the target shape).

Comment: The size of the Point clouds is resized to a common size. The size of points belonging together varies.

Comment: ok, solved it by countig the size befor passing the arrays to the list